# Не добавляет File в список

Tags: java

```
public void addFileToList(File file) throws IOException 
{
    for(File f:myList)
    {
        if (!FileUtils.contentEquals(f,file))
            myList.add(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Потому что, если `myList` - изначально пустой, в него никогда ничего не добавится.
2. В коде вопроса делается попытка добавить файл в список, если там есть хотя бы один файл, который отличается от `file`.
3. Попытка изменить массив во время итерации по нему приведет к исключению.

---

```
bool found = false;

for(File f:myList)
{
  if (FileUtils.contentEquals(f,file))
  {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (!found)
{
  myList.add(file);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо.Но так вылетает исключение  java.util.ConcurrentModificationException